# InApp Purchase Clarification

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, in-app-purchase, mkstorekit

I have an App that I want to have two version in the App store, one is the lite version and the other is a full version.  I would like to have the lite version offered as free with the option to upgrade using InApp Purchase.  The full version will be offered for a price.

For InApp purchases in my other apps, i used MKStoreKit to do the InApp Purchase of my non-consumable product (upgrade).  For the lite version I am ok with that approach.

My question is, for the full version that will be available in the App store for a cost, do I need to use something like MKStoreKit, or can I just publish it and Apple handle the purchase because they know it costs to download?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason why you should include MKStoreKit in the full version if it won't be using it.

You may want to build both apps from the same code base though (that's what I do for my own app, which like yours comes in a Freemium and Paid version), and have your XCode project build two targets, one for each. But even when doing so, you can exclude MKStoreKit in the full version and only include it in the freemium version.

Comment: And to make the distinction in the code whilst keeping the code exactly the same, you can use a preprocessor symbol and define it only in one of the versions (for example FREE_VERSION). Then in your code do an `#if FREE_VERSION` and stick your in-app purchase logic in there.

Comment: Yes, that is what I was thinking also.  In xCode, how can I conditionally include the store and security frameworks, or will they get stripped out of the full version because they are not needed?

Comment: You can change all the settings for each target, so you could simply remove these two frameworks in the settings for the full version (I think it's on the Build Phases page). Then again, leaving them in is not harmful (it just makes your app bundle bigger than it needs be).

Answer (score 0):

You only need MKStoreKit if you're doing an in-app purchase.  So for the app that is the paid version, you will not need it.

Comment: Ok, thanks! So do I need to build my app as two different version, or can I publish the lite version to the app store and detect in the code if it was the paid version.  Or do I need to keep two different code sets?

Comment: I'd build it as two Targets as part of the same Xcode project.  You will be able to share the code that makes sense to share.

Answer (score 0):

Going by your question, it seems you might think you can have an in app purchase that downloads the full version from the app store. This is not possible.
You need 2 seperate version and in the free one to keep it all locked down unless they have made the in app purchase to unlock it all. If it has 'free' or 'lite' in the app title, they'll still have this even after unlocking the full thing as the app itself won't change.

Comment: No, that is understood.  To explain, I would have two version Lite and Full, Lite will be built with InApp Purchase and Full will be built without InApp Purchase and all features enabled. Both get published to the App Store.  When the user downloads Lite (for free) they can upgrade at any time via InApp Purchase and that would unlock the missing features. When the user download the Full version they get it all and there is no InApp purchase.